# Java doesnt accept unsigned bytes, and i am trying to map them

Tags: java, dictionary, byte, unsigned

I need to map 2 bytes, so that if the starting position (or a rgb color, which is coded in bytes) starts with 255 (or anything above 127), and it needs to end at 0, in a row of for example 30 segments. The maths is quite easy: You just make ((0-255*segment)/30)(255-0) and for each segment you will have a bit less of the byte. It is just the maths for lineal blending
Anyway, other languages have a funtion called map that does just that. [Example of Map in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)
But the problem is I need this funtion in java. So I decided to make my own. The reason is because I need to blend the colors from one side to another. So i made this simple aplication, but it doesnt work because when the bytes calculated go above 127, java thinks its value is under the starting point.
The code is here. the first funtion is the java method that tries to fade, and the second funtion is the funtion that tries to do the mapping calculation:

```
public ColorRGB[] olas(ColorRGB color1, ColorRGB color2) {          
    ColorRGB[] colordevuelto=new ColorRGB[30];
    byte longuitud=30;  
    //so we get two colors and fade and merge them at some point
    for(byte h=0;h<longuitud;h++) {
        byte rojofinal= map(color1.getRed(),color2.getRed(),(byte) 0,longuitud,h);  
        byte azulfinal= map(color1.getBlue(),color2.getBlue(),(byte) 0,longuitud,h);
        byte verdefinal= map(color1.getGreen(),color2.getGreen(),(byte) 0,longuitud,h);
        System.out.println("Led num: "+h+"Componente roja: "+ Byte.toString(rojofinal)+" componente verde: "+Byte.toString(verdefinal)+" componente azul "+Byte.toString(azulfinal));
        colordevuelto[h]=new ColorRGB(rojofinal,verdefinal,azulfinal);
    }
    return colordevuelto;   //devuelve un array de color fadeado a lo largo de 30 pixeles
}
private byte map (byte xinicio, byte xfinal,byte ymin,byte ymax, byte point) {
    //this funtion is for mapping from one side to another
    if(point > ymax || point <ymin) {
        return 0;   //Esto no deberia pasar nunca
    }

    if(xfinal>xinicio) {
        return (byte) (((xfinal-xinicio)*point)/(ymax-ymin));
    }
    else {
        return (byte) (((xfinal-xinicio)*point)/(ymax-ymin)+(xinicio-xfinal));
    }


}
```

Comment: What is ColorRGB? Can you post it's code?

Comment: @Eugene Right, thank you.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, but why not use `char` with it's 16 bits, or `int` with a mask if you really what that?

Comment: To turn a byte `b` into a 0-255 value you can do `b & 0xFF` and now it's an unsigned byte (actually it's an `int` but has the range of an unsigned byte)

Comment: @PeterLawrey probably make that an answer, I was really lazy to put that in, I would upvote

Answer (score 1):

While language support for unsigned bytes would have been nice, possibly a better choice than signed bytes, you can convert one to another pretty easily.

```
byte b = // some signed value
int unsigned = b & 0xFF;
```

In short, do all your calculations as `int` values and only cast to a byte for storage, or compatibility.

Since you are blending over perhaps a wide number of pixels, you could even use `float` or `double` for your calculations, and cast to byte when needed.